# How to store and get value from variable of serializable class?

Tags: unity-game-engine

**I need to store value to my serializable class than use it to my save function at JsonCharacterSaver class**

---

*first I just used unity and c#, my base is web developer (somehow it might help).*

---

*then I get the following code from the results of applying the tutorial to the JSON section (https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/scripting/introduction-saving-and-loading).*

---

I have read about serialize and several pages of related tutorials on the page provided by Unity but did not find a way or solution that was needed. the biggest problem is I don't know where I don't know and I don't know what I should find out

---

*nb. sorry if im doing wrong with my format of question this is my 2nd time as long as i remember*

---

***Below is  my save class***

```c#
using System.IO;
using UnityEngine;

public class JsonCharacterSaver : MonoBehaviour
{
    public CharacterData characterData;
    string dataPath;

    void Start ()
    {
       dataPath = Path.Combine(Application.persistentDataPath, "CharacterData.txt");
    }

    void Update ()
    {
        if(Input.GetKeyDown (KeyCode.S))
          SaveCharacter (characterData, dataPath);
    }

    static void SaveCharacter (CharacterData data, string path)
    {
        string jsonString = JsonUtility.ToJson (data);

        using (StreamWriter streamWriter = File.CreateText (path))
        {
            streamWriter.Write (jsonString);
        }
    }
}
```

---

***Below is  my addGold function***

```c#
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class addGold : MonoBehaviour
{
    public CharacterData characterData;

    public void addinggold()
    {
        this.characterData.golds += 20;
        Debug.Log(this.characterData.golds);
    }
}
```

---

***Below is  my seriazable class***

```c#
using System;

[Serializable]
public class CharacterData
{
    public int golds;
}
```

Comment: None of your code says that `public CharacterData characterData;` in your JsonCharacterSaver class and the `public CharacterData characterData;` in your addGold class refer to the same object.

Comment: Thats what im thought. And the question is how to relate that public CharacterData characterData. So when my addgold save that store to my chatacter data and when json call the character data that retrieve the character data value.

Comment: You can't make two fields in two unrelated classes "relate" to each other. You have to, at some point, somewhere, assign a value to each one. Not knowing how you're doing that, I can't say what might  be going wrong. That said, you probably shouldn't be storing it in a field in *either* of these two classes. For example, your save class should get it passed [as a parameter](https://github.com/Draco18s/IdleArtificer/blob/master/Assets/draco18s/util/DataAccess.cs#L19) to the save function.

Comment: so the conclusion of the thing I asked above is that it can't be done, right?
Ok then thank you for your time. Happy New Year!

Comment: You *can* make them point to the same object, the problem is that you can't *enforce* that relationship: you have to do it all manually. However, there's no reason to have those fields *at all* to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

well you somehow have to have a reference between two components

I would do it in the **JsonCharacterSaver**

```c#
using System.IO;
using UnityEngine;

public class JsonCharacterSaver : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Here you reference the addGold component in the inspector (drag&drop)
    public addGold addGoldReference;

    string dataPath;

    void Start ()
    {
       dataPath = Path.Combine(Application.persistentDataPath, "CharacterData.txt");
    }

    void Update ()
    {
      if(Input.GetKeyDown (KeyCode.S))
        // Now here use the data from the reference instead
        SaveCharacter (addGoldReference.characterData, dataPath);
    }

    static void SaveCharacter (CharacterData data, string path)
    {
        string jsonString = JsonUtility.ToJson (data);

        using (StreamWriter streamWriter = File.CreateText (path))
        {
            streamWriter.Write (jsonString);
        }
    }
}
```

---

And additionally for more complex settings, data etc you should have a look at [ScritableObjects](https://unity3d.com/de/learn/tutorials/modules/beginner/live-training-archive/scriptable-objects).

The huge advantage is you can save your value here and also have the according behaviours like loading and storing all on only one script. You also can have different data setups and change the `MonoBehaviours` by jst referencing different ScriptableObject instances (assets) etc. In your case e.g.

```c#
[CreateAssetMenu(fileName = "new CharacterData", menuName = "Example/CharacterDataSsset", order = 1)]
public class CharacterData
{
    public int golds;

    public void SaveToFile(string path)
    {
        string jsonString = JsonUtility.ToJson (this);

        using (StreamWriter streamWriter = File.CreateText (path))
        {
            streamWriter.Write (jsonString);
        }
    }
}
```

Now you create a new CharacterData asset by right-click in the `ProjectsView` (Assets) and in the menu find `Example` -> `CharacterDataAsset` and reference it (inspector) in the `addGold` component.

and in **JsonCharacterSaver** only do

```c#
void Update ()
{
  if(Input.GetKeyDown (KeyCode.S))
    // Now here use the data from the reference instead
    addGoldReference.characterData.SaveToFile(dataPath);
}
```